# Knockout, how to bind observable object to select

Tags: knockout.js

Refer to jsfiddle.net/SimonYong/qS3Qa/
How can I bind my Choices to select box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't push `ko.observable()`'s onto a `ko.observableArray()`. Here's a fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/qS3Qa/1/